# ¿Cómo puedo colocar dos iframe en una misma linea?

Tags: html, css

He podido establecerlo pero con una tabla de por medio y siento que no es la mejor manera ya que luego editaré los estilos con javascript para que se oculte un iframe y el otro ocupe todo el espacio. este es el código:

```html
<div class="main-container">
      <table style="width: 100% !important;height: 100%;">
        <tr>
          <td>
              <iframe id="container-form" src="https://picsum.photos/800" style="width: 100% !important;height: 100%;"></iframe>
          </td>
          <td>
              <iframe id="container-imagen" src="https://picsum.photos/800" style="width: 100% !important;height: 100%;"></iframe>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

De preferencia cambiar las etiquetas o agregar algún estilo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El contenedor tiene el **100%**, y los div internos el **50%**.

```css
.main-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.div-mitad {
  width: 50%;
  float: left; 
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="div-mitad"> 
    <iframe id="container-form" src="https://picsum.photos/800" style="width: 100% !important;height: 100%;"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="div-mitad"> 
    <iframe id="container-imagen" src="https://picsum.photos/800" style="width: 100% !important;height: 100%;"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Para toda la altura de la página puedes usar `height: 100vh;` y ver los detalles en esta otra respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/a/43747245/2100126

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la variante del Grid CSS, el código queda bastante limpio.

En código cuando ocultes una columna puedes establecer además `grid-template-columns: 100% 0%;` o `grid-template-columns: 0% 100%;` de manera dinámica.

Para ocupar todo el algo de la página puedes usar `height: 100vh;` como se describe en la respuesta a la otra pregunta "[force css grid container to fill full screen of device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43747245/2100126)"

```css
.main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
      <iframe id="container-form" src="https://picsum.photos/800"></iframe>
      <iframe id="container-imagen" src="https://picsum.photos/800"></iframe>
</div>
```